# Having trouble understanding the K-way merge algorithm (Counter example given)

Tags: algorithm, heap

In K way merge sort, the solution that uses a heap: essentially maintains a heap and constantly extracts max from that heap. I have a counterexample for why this won't work well.

```
5 -> 1 -> 0
4 -> 2 -> 1
3 -> 2 -> 0
```

Suppose we initialize our heap. It contains {5, 4, 3}.

We run extract max, we obtain 5 and add that into our new list (that represents the final solution). Our heap now looks like {4,3}. We then refill our heap with the head of list that we extracted the max element from.

This implies that we get something like this: {4, 3, 1}.

This doesn't make sense to me. This heap doesn't represent the top K elements anymore. 1 shouldn't be used to refill the heap, it should have been 2. So, this `O(nlgk)` method doesn't make much sense to me.

I hope someone can shed light on how this algorithm works because I'm stuck here.

Comment: The heap doesn't need to have to top K elements.  It only needs to contain the biggest element.

Comment: Ah, I see. How do we ensure (or prove rather) that it will always contain the biggest element? This approach is rather unintuitive to me.

Comment: Actually, see the comments in the answer. It elaborates on the structure of the elements in the heap./

Comment: It always contains the largest element from each source, so it always contains the largest element.

Comment: Yeah - that makes sense. There's some structure to the elements in the heap. That's super cool. (It would be unsatisfying if it was just random)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max heap always contains the max elements of k lists (or arrays). For your 'counter' example:

```
5 -> 1 -> 0
4 -> 2 -> 1
3 -> 2 -> 0
```

The heap is  {5, 4, 3} contains max elements of these three lists.

Now you extract 5 from the heap, means you also remove 5 from the first list:

```
5-->1-->0: after extract 5, the list now is 1-->0: so 1 now is the top of the list.
```

Then the new heap is {4, 3, 1}, still contains max elements of lists.

Lets continue your example: the current heap after extracting 5 and heapifying is:

```
{4, 3, 1}
```

Extract 4 from the heap, means you also remove 4 from:

```
4-->2-->1: remove 4 you have 2-->1. 2 now is the top element of the list.
```

Then a new heap now is

```
{3, 2, 1}
```

Keep doing this, you get what you want (descending list).

Comment: `The max heap always contains the max elements of k lists (or arrays). For your 'counter' example`

No it doesn't. If it did, it would have contained {4,3,2}.

Comment: 2 is not the max of any list, as explained when you remove 5 from 5-->1-->0: 1 now is the max of the list.

Comment: Oh, I see. This makes sense to me now.